# ffmpeg: corrupted video when using a different source image

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using the exact same command on two different images, to create a zoom in effect:

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -i image1.jpg -filter_complex "scale=-2:10*ih,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)',scale=-2:720" -y -shortest -c:v libx264 test1.mp4
```

With image1.jpg, the video output is fine, but with image2.jpg it seems to be corrupted: although I can read the output video in VLC, I don't see its thumbnail under Windows, and Adobe Premiere can't read this file in the timeline.

The two images are jpg downloaded from the web, and they both have the same ratio.

What I am missing?

Comment: Provide `image2.jpg` and show the complete console output from the command using this image.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard this is my console output, it looks similar to what I have with image1.jpg : http://pastebin.com/ya0BPCp2 and this is image2.jpg : http://hpics.li/8eea820 Note that I have found another image giving the same corrupted result, so it might be due more to the program than the picture.

Comment: Duplicate of [FFmpeg converting image sequence to video results in blank video](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13166766/1109017).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard you're correct, adding -pix_fmt yuv420p as an output option fixes it. Our problems seemed quite unrelated though, so I don't know if it's really a duplicate

Comment: It's the same issue. But instead of using `-pix_fmt yuv420p` end your filterchain with the format filter: `...,scale=-2:720,format=yuv420p`. That way all of your filtering stuff is contained in your filtergraph.